# Weird build error,issue with class name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm doing a short project just to experiment writing without the use of nib files (personal interest only, don't plan on never using nibs!).

I have my app controller set up as NSApp's delegate. Under -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification, I attempt to initialize the interface.

AppController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject {

NSWindow* mainWindow;
QTMovieView* movieView;
QTCaptureSession* mainSession;
QTCaptureMovieFileOutput* output;
QTCaptureDeviceInput* video;
QTCaptureDeviceInput* audio;

}

+ (void)initialize;
- (id)init;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification;

@end
```

Method in AppController.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {


//Proceed to initialize the entire interface:

mainWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(500, 300, 700, 500)
styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask|
  NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask) 
backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
defer:NO];

[mainWindow setTitle:@"Record a movie!"];

/*movieView = [[QTMovieView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect([[mainWindow contentView] bounds].origin.x + 5, 
                                                [[mainWindow contentView] bounds].origin.y + 30,
                                                    [[mainWindow contentView] bounds].size.width - 10, 
                                                    [[mainWindow contentView] bounds].size.height - 35)];*/

[[mainWindow contentView] addSubview:movieView];

[mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

}
```

The part commented out is the origin of the 1 error that doesn't appear in the text editor, only in the "build" panel:

```
<pre> ".objc_class_name_QTMovieView", referenced from:  
literal-pointer@_OBJC@_cls_refs@QTMovieView in AppController.o
symbol(s) not found
collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

There seems to be a problem with alloc/init'ing an instance here. I can declare a new one just fine, i.e. QTMovieView *test; and nothing complains. I've also found that it does the same thing with all the other QT classes when I try to alloc/init them. However, I was able to alloc/init NSWindow just fine. The framework is in my project and as you can see in my .h file, I included QTKit.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're getting is a linker error -- the linker (`ld`) can't find the framework object code for the `QTMovieView` class.  Therefore, you haven't included the QTKit framework in your project.  If you think you have, then something about it isn't set up properly.

Comment: Thanks, turned out I had added "QuickTime.framework" instead of "QTKit.framework"... bleh...